# How to launch java swing app which used precompled DLL from cmd?

Tags: java, windows, dll, java-native-interface

When i'm using double click my java app starts perfectly.
My path:

```
PATH=...C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;...
```

But when i'm running app from cmd:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin>java.exe -jar C:\Users\zagorulkinde\Docume
nts\ps_client_lib\bin\Win32\GUItest.jar
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Window
s\System32\pc_client_lib.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1928)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
        at PC_client.lib.<clinit>(lib.java:10)
        at settings.load(GUItest.java:342)
        at GUItest.createAndShowGUI(GUItest.java:2681)
        at GUItest.access$4100(GUItest.java:851)
        at GUItest$22.run(GUItest.java:2728)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:211)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.
java:128)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:117)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

i am trying to run with x86 java version:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin>java.exe -jar C:\Users\zagorulkinde\
Documents\ps_client_lib\bin\Win32\GUItest.jar
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no PC_cli
ent_lib in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
        at PC_client.lib.<clinit>(lib.java:10)
        at settings.load(GUItest.java:342)
        at GUItest.createAndShowGUI(GUItest.java:2681)
        at GUItest.access$4100(GUItest.java:851)
        at GUItest$22.run(GUItest.java:2728)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:244)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.
java:163)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:151)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

if i am trying to specify dll:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin>java.exe -Djava.library.path="C:\Use
rs\zagorulkinde\Documents\ps_client_lib\bin\Win32\Pc_client_lib.dll" -jar C:\Use
rs\zagorulkinde\Documents\ps_client_lib\bin\Win32\GUItest.jar
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no PC_cli
ent_lib in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
        at PC_client.lib.<clinit>(lib.java:10)
        at settings.load(GUItest.java:342)
        at GUItest.createAndShowGUI(GUItest.java:2681)
        at GUItest.access$4100(GUItest.java:851)
        at GUItest$22.run(GUItest.java:2728)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:244)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.
java:163)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:151)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

What i am doing wrong? Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) -Djava.library.path specifies the *path* to where native libraries live, it doesn't specify the libraries themselves. (i.e. - take the filename out, change it to `-Djava.library.path="C:\Use
rs\zagorulkinde\Documents\ps_client_lib\bin\Win32\"`)

2.) Case-sensitivity might be an issue - you're referencing the file as "Pc_client_lib.dll" and "PC_client_lib" in different places. Make sure the name you use in `loadLibrary` has the same case as the actual .DLL file name.

Comment: the same error: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\ zagorulkinde\Documents\ps_client_lib\bin\Win32\Pc_client_lib.dll: Can't find dep endent libraries`. in this dir exists `Pc_client_lib.dll`

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry - it's not "the same error" - `Can't find dependent libraries` means Java has now found the .DLL you specified, but the .DLL itself has dependencies that aren't available on the PATH or java.library.path. You'll need to find what other .DLL files `Pc_client_lib.dll` needs and add them too.

Comment: i put all `DLLs` in system32 folder in and replace string with `Djava.library.path="C:\Widows\System32"` i got this error:` java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no PC_clent_lib in java.library.path`

Comment: Then you're back to the original issue.  And added more. 1.) "C:\Windows\system32" should be on the PATH by default so not sure why you're even adding to java.library path.  2.) "system32" starts with a lower-case "s". 3.) And is it 'Pc_client_lib.dll' or 'PC_client_lib.dll'?

Comment: `Pc_client_lib.dll` and `PC_client_lib.dll` exist in `System32`. the same error `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no PC_client_lib in java.library.path`

Comment: You've probably mis-typed something in the `-Djava.library.path` (I see `C:\Widows\System32` in the comment above - make sure it's "Wi **n** dows" instead of "Widows" )

Comment: it's ok. i'm using <tab> when typing.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put your DLL to place where JVM can find it. Typically it should be located under your application folder but you should specify option `-Djava.library.path=PATH TO YOUR DLL` when you are running java.

Comment: the same error:  `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\
zagorulkinde\Documents\ps_client_lib\bin\Win32\Pc_client_lib.dll: Can't find dep
endent libraries`

Answer (score 0):

Safest way is to put your DLL file into `system32` folder.

Comment: in this situation:` C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin>java.exe -jar C:\Users\zagorulkinde\Documents\ps_client_lib\bin\Win32\GUItest.jar` my system32 dir has this lib

Comment: sorry I didn't understand @ZagorulkinDmitry