# Compile 32 bit Java builds on 64 bit machine with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, build, 64-bit, 32-bit

so the questions as in the title, I need to run my server application in Tomcat on a System which is 32 bit Windows XP, I am working and compiling on my 64 bit Windows 7 in Eclipse. How do I compile it to 32 bit, what do I need to do? I assume it won't work on the 32 bit Windows when I'm compiling it on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: it all depends what jdk you have installed on your machine.

Comment: Unless you are building native libraries as part of your build procedure ... your assumption is incorrect.

Comment: @StephenC Well I was so glad about what you said, that my assumption wasn't correct, however when I tried running it it said: "Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform"
So I assume it usually matters what platform you're using...? I need to compile for 32 bit somehow

Comment: @ArturasM - Then either you *are* building a native library as part of your build (and you have to figure out how to cross-compile that native library) or the native library is a dependency (and you have to download, etc the version that matches your platform).  But the fact that you have DLLs at all means that this is not a pure Java application you are building.

Comment: @ArturasM - I think you need to get your head around the nature of the software you are building here, where this DLL is coming from, and whether you are actually building it as part of this build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't build 32-bit or 64-bit applications - bytecode is portable across different bit architectures.

The only exception is native libraries that you might be using in your code. If there are any then you will have to manually compile those for the respective platform. Otherwise the java code is totally portable across 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.

Comment: Hmm, it says: "Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform"

Comment: dlls are not java libs those are platform dependent. As mentioned in the answer "The only exception is native libraries that you might be using in your code". As far as java libraries are concerned they are portable

Comment: Ya, bytecode is, but java has this thing called jni which defeats that quite brutally.

Comment: @DusteD native code refers to all JNI(java native interface) related suff in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your JNI DLL, which needs to be compiled for 32-bit to match the 32-bit JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Java is independent of the OS.

You can compile with your 64bit machine and run this on a 32bit computer as long as this computer has a 32bit VM.

Comment: Hmm, it says: "Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform"

Answer (score 0):

If you're still searching for some "simple" solution, one would be to install a 32 bit os in a virtual machine and run eclipse from there.. Very ugly I know, but it works.

Another approach is mentioned here. [How to launch java swing app which used precompled DLL from cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820703/how-to-launch-java-swing-app-which-used-precompled-dll-from-cmd)

Answer (score 0):

You could install a 32bits jdk on a 64bits machine. point the JAVA_HOME to this jdk and use it. It