# Single installer for Windows 32-bit and 64-bit of JavaFX application

Tags: java, windows, javafx, exe

I am developing a JavaFX application in a 64 bit windows machine.
But after creating an MSI installer of my application it's only running on 64 bit machines and showing **version file is not compatible with the version of windows you're running** on 32 bit windows pc.

I want to know that is there any way to create a single installer which will work on both the 32 bit and 64 bit windows machine?

Comment: How are you creating an MSI installer?

Comment: If you are using Netbeans. https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html

Comment: yes i m creating MSI through the link given by @Sedrick

Comment: That link explains how to create an `EXE`.

Comment: Yes exe generated by that process is not running on 32 bit windows

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought it would work for `32-bit`.

Comment: `"You could install a 32bits jdk on a 64bits machine. point the JAVA_HOME to this jdk and use it. It"` <-
 from -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145781/compile-32-bit-java-builds-on-64-bit-machine-with-eclipse sounds promising.

Comment: Ya i have to give one shot at that thanks.

Comment: after installing 32 bit JDK i changed JAVA_HOME but when i tried **java -version** in cmd still showing me 64 bit server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Sedrick comment.

I solved my problem by

1)installing 32 bit JDK

2)Sets the **JAVA_HOME** path to it's jdk

3)Changed netbeans JDK platform which i got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950960/how-to-set-the-jdk-netbeans-runs-on)

4)And finally build the project

And got my 32 bit JavaFX application EXE