# How to get JDK 8 - 32 bit for Mac OS X for Openhab development?

Tags: java, java-8, openhab

According to [openhab tutorial](https://www.openhab.org/docs/installation/) they said that openhab developers should use JDK 8 - 32 bit for Mac OSX, How can I install JDK 8 - 32 bit, the only available version of JDK 8 is 64 bit !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have misread the documentation. [This page](https://www.openhab.org/docs/installation/#prerequisites) notes that you must use 32-bit Java on ARM chips, rather than 64-bit.

> Please use the **32-bit version** of the JVM for ARM platforms, even on 64-bit operating systems. Serial connections won't work with a 64-bit JVM, preventing bindings like Z-Wave from functioning.

ARM chips are used in many of the home automation devices and used in computers such as the Raspberry Pi. But ARM chips are *not* used in Macs, which currently use 64-bit Intel Core chips.

According to [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17145781/642706), Java apps are agnostic regarding their host OS being 32-bit or 64-bit. Only native-code libraries called from Java may care about 32/64 bits of the host OS.

I’m not a user of OpenHAB, so I’m not certain

I give up… Stack Overflow is losing my edits.

Answer (score 1):

All the recent Macs run [64-bit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit) [macOS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS).

If you still want to install JDK32 bit, you can have any OS using a virtual machine (VMware Fusion, Parallels, or VirtualBox) and then install JDK inside that VM.

For the openHAB recommended is to use [Zulu](https://zulu.org/download/?show=all).

More accurate answer provided by: Basil Bourque